# React input value persists across modal re-renders, even though state is updated correctly. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-rain-4cl4iy?file=/src/App.js

I have a table as below:
[image]

When I click the 'edit' button it opens up a modal like below where I can then edit the input fields (onChange listener updates state):
[image]

Once I click 'save', it makes a 'fetch' call to save the data to backend and then closes the modal. If I click 'edit' on any other row the changed field is persisted as below:
[image]

Inspecting the element and looking at the state the values are correct:
[image]

Background on the code:

- I am passing in the row's data as a prop to this modal
- In the modal I'm using `useEffect` to re-render when the prop gets updated (when a different row's 'edit' button is pressed)

The props are being passed correctly, the state is being set correctly and only on changing the value of the input does the new value persist across modals. I'd like to fill the value of input from the props every time a new modal is opened.

Below are code snippets:

Passing data as a prop:

```
<EditConnectionModal connection={connection} setConnection={setConnection} initials={initials} getConnections={getConnections} />
```

Input:

```
                                        <header class="form-floating">
                                            <input class="border rounded form-control form-control-lg text-light bg-dark-2" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" defaultValue={name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
                                            <label class="form-label text-start text-white-50" for="name">Full Name</label>
                                        </header>
```

States and useEffect:

```
    const [name, setName] = React.useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")
    const [company, setCompany] = React.useState("")
    const [website, setWebsite] = React.useState("")
```

```
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setName(connection.name)
        setEmail(connection.email)
        setCompany(connection.company)
        setWebsite(connection.website)
    }, [user, isAuthenticated, connection])
```

Comment: add stackblitz or codesandbox

Comment: also screenshot wont help alone add code snippet

Comment: Added code snippets, I hope that's more clear.

Comment: Pictures are pretty, but we really need to see a [mcve] of the code producing the issue. We can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Comment: Ok that's fair. I will build a sandbox and repost the question.

Comment: Here is a link to a sandbox that has most of the code - https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-rain-4cl4iy?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what was wrong.

I was using bootstrap actions directly (data-bs-toggle, data-bs-dismiss, etc.) to invoke actions like open/close a modal. This interfered with the react event handler system and cause unexpected bugs.

In this specific case, the modal was being rendered on page load and NOT when the modal was opened. Hence it was being fed wrong props, hence overwriting the textbox with an unexpected value.

SOLUTION: Use state variables and react components to create and handle events like open/close a modal.

This is probably a simple and obvious answer but I'm new to react and this was an important lesson to learn the hard way.